# regarding shopping cart site

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

hi guys problem with basket.
can any one tell me the source code for add the cart with basket item. i have  a three  additional product named royal, splroyal, postal which has a amount value 22$ 45 $ 90$.
these all are stored in radio button. first off in the php how do i call the radio function
also wanna to know about the jquery code for this here there is no need for store the db.give me some ideas or post some code.

thanks

```
form method="post" form name="make_payment_frm" action="module/make-payment-module.php" onsubmit="return show_make_payment_validation();" 

input name="rmr"  type="radio" value="30" onclick="get_radio_value()"/royal
input name="rmr"  type="radio" value="52" onclick="get_radio_value()"/splroyal
input name="rmr"  type="radio" value="37" onclick="get_radio_value()"/postal
```

Answer (score 0):

Save it into session, but first of all, change the value attributes, so they are unique.

Then you can make a standard or Ajax request to your PHP script, which reads product identifier, and saves it into session. In PHP, you can read radio value just like other input fileds - it will be in $_REQUEST (better use $_POST or $_GET), containing value that is present in value attribute of radio button user had chosen.

Example PHP code (please implement more security mechanisms before using):

```
<?php
     session_start();

     $itemId = $_POST['rmr'];

     if(!empty($itemId)){
        $_SESSION['cart'][] = $itemId;
     }
?>
```

That is the most simple example I can give you ;)

Nice day

Update:

First, change you html to something like that:

```
<form method="post" form name="make_payment_frm" action="module/make-payment-module.php" onsubmit="return show_make_payment_validation();"> 
      <input name="rmr"  type="radio" value="1" onclick="get_radio_value()" /> royal<br />
      <input name="rmr"  type="radio" value="2" onclick="get_radio_value()" /> splroyal<br />
      <input name="rmr"  type="radio" value="3" onclick="get_radio_value()" /> postal
</form>
```

Then, you have two options: first one is to send data via AJAX. You'd do that in Javascript, in show_make_payment_validation() function. If you're using jQuery, request would look something like that:

```
$.post('module/make-payment-module.php', {rmr : $('name="rmr"').val()}, function(data){
   // callback
});
```

and read it in PHP just like I described above. If you're using other JS framework or none at all, take a look at XmlHttpRequest.

Second is to get rid of that function and post directly. Then, in PHP, you access the data as I mentioned before, `$_POST['rmr']` is you cart item (it'll be 1 if royal is selected, 2 if splroyal and 3 if postal).

Comment: i have the doubt with request function.how to declare the variable with REQUEST

Comment: @can you write down $rmr = $_REQUEST['rmr']; $delivery_mail_details = $rmr; if you see in ajax data i have the confusion.it asks action

Comment: Updated my answer with some details. Basically, if you POST, you use $_POST to retrieve value in PHP. If you use GET, you use $_GET to retrieve value in PHP. :)

Comment: you are great usoban.in data what should i give it .

Comment: either itz write or wrong Mr.usoban $(document).ready(function(){ 
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){ 
    var price = $(this).attr("value");
    var name =  $(this).attr("rmr");

 add_payment_value(price); 
  });  
 });  
function add_payment_value(price){ 
 // here you can use $.ajax function to add your 'price value' to your cart 
   $.ajax({ 
   type: "POST", 
   url: "make-payment.php"// file where you can add price to your database 
   data: " ", 
   success: function(){} // return something on success 
     }); 
   }